# Intento que al pinchar en la cabecera me ordene esa columna de elementos, pero no me detecta la señal. alguien sabe como solucionarlo?

Tags: c++, qt

**`connect(tableView->horizontalHeader(), SIGNAL(clicked(int)), this, SLOT(ordenar(int)));`**

en el header declaro

```
private slots:

void ordenar(int logicalIndex);

void MainWindow::ordenar(int logicalIndex )
{



    QString id;
    mModel=new QSqlQueryModel(this);

    if (logicalIndex==1){id="grupo";}
    if (logicalIndex==2){id="tipo";}
    if (logicalIndex==3){id="nombre";}
    if (logicalIndex==4){id="descripcion";}
    else{
        id="id";
    }
    QString campo=comboCampo->currentText();
    QString cond=comboCondicion->currentText();
    QString valor=comboValor->currentText();
    QString multi=comboMulti->currentText();
    QString campo2=comboCampo2->currentText();
    QString cond2=comboCondicion2->currentText();
    QString valor2=comboValor2->currentText();
    if(filtro==1){
        if(comboMulti->currentIndex()!=0){
            mModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM vertical WHERE " +campo+ " "+cond +" '"+valor+"' " +multi+" " +campo2+ " "+cond2 +" '"+valor2+"' ORDER BY '"+id+"';");}
        else {mModel->setQuery("SELECT * FROM vertical WHERE " +campo+ " "+cond +" '"+valor+"' ORDER BY '"+id+"';");}
    }
    if(filtro!=1){
        mModel->setQuery("SELECT id,grupo,tipo,nombre,descripcion,icono from vertical ORDER BY '"+id+"';");
    }
    mModel->setHeaderData(0,Qt::Horizontal,tr("ID"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(1,Qt::Horizontal,tr("GRUPO"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(2,Qt::Horizontal,tr("TIPO"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(3,Qt::Horizontal,tr("NOMBRE"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(4,Qt::Horizontal,tr("DESCRIPCI\u00D3N"));
    mModel->setHeaderData(5,Qt::Horizontal,tr("ICONO"));

    tableView->setModel(mModel);
    tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
    tableView->show();


}
```

Esto es lo que me sale por consola cuando hago click en la cabecera de la tabla:

> Object::connect: No such signal QHeaderView::clicked() in ..\signal_dev\mainwindow.cpp:362

Comment: Object::connect: No such signal QHeaderView::clicked() in ..\signal_dev\mainwindow.cpp:362 esto es lo que me sale por consola cuando hago click en la cabecera de la tabla

Comment: Esa información debería ir en la pregunta. La gente no espera tener que leerse los comentarios para saber de qué va la pregunta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si revisas la documentación de [Qt](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qheaderview.html#signals), verás que `QHeaderView` no dispone de una señal `clicked()`.

¿Cómo se realiza la ordenación por columnas?

Lo primero es habilitar la ordenación en el `QTableView`. Para ello hay que llamar a `setSortingEnabled()`:

```
QTableView * tableView;
tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
```

Esto habilita los botones de ordenación en las cabeceras de la tabla... pero por si solo verás que no hace nada. Por cierto, esta propiedad se puede modificar en el editor de formularios de Qt.

Adicionalmente la ordenación se suele realizar a través de un *proxy*. El sistema de modelos de Qt suele estar estructurado de la siguiente forma:

- Modelo principal: contiene los datos debidamente estructurados (es el que estás rellenando actualmente)
- Proxy: Se ubica entre el modelo principal y la vista. Gestiona las operaciones de ordenación y filtrado. Al no tocar el modelo principial la programación se simplifica enormemente.
- Vista: Recibe un modelo o un proxy y presenta la información que el mismo le ofrece.

Si no necesitas una ordenación específica de los datos puedes hacer uso de uno de los [proxys](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qsortfilterproxymodel.html) que Qt trae por defecto:

```
TableView* tableView;
QSqlQueryModel* mModel;
// ...

tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
QSortFilterProxyModel* proxy = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
proxy->setSourceModel(mModel);

tableView->setModel(proxy);
```

Tras esta configuración los datos de la tabla deberían poder ordenarse automáticamente al trastear las cabeceras de la tabla.

Comment: declaro el proxy en la cabecera e importo  y añado esto al código
    tableView->setSortingEnabled(true);
    proxy = new QSortFilterProxyModel(this);
    proxy->setSourceModel(mModel);    tableView->setModel(proxy);                                              Pero no funciona

Comment: Muchas gracias, eres un crack , ya me funciona tenia que borrar lo anterior , fallo mio

Comment: @AntonioVelosoGomez Genial. Un saludo